# How to check if model's attached items have changed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Suppose we have `Class` and `Student` models with many-to-many relationship defined between them.

I want to perform some action, if `$students`, that are attached to a `$class`, change. For example:

```
$class->attach($newSetOfStudents); // notify a teacher about the change behind the scenes
$class->save();                    // by overriden save() or attach() methods
```

How can this be accomplished? I tried to use `..->isDirty()` when overriding the `save()` method, but it does not seem to work with attached models.

**Update**

Checking the pivots for `..->isDirty()` doesn't seem to work either:

```
// ..
foreach($class->students as $student){
    if($student->pivot->isDirty()) return true;
}
// ..
```

Comment: have a method on your Class model (say, saveNewSetOfStudents) to encapsulate the attach and save methods, and also add any other logic you require.

Comment: Well, it will work, however it may lead to bugs in the future. For example, if another developer, or even I, forget that attachment needs to happen only by means of that method and use regular `attach()`. So that approach isn't that "clean" so to say.

Answer (score 1):

the best thing to do, is using beforeSave() method by extending `Ardent`, there you can handle the case you want, do the changes, let it go to the save method by its own.

take a look at this nice [package](https://github.com/laravel-ardent/ardent)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Model Event - `created` on `Pivot` like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

Pivot::created(function($pivot) {
 // Do something here
});
```

This solutions fires for each pivot & only works in case of `attach()`.

See more about this - [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-attach-which-event-is-fired?page=1)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, the event's aren't firing.. Tried all of them + placed them both in `EventServiceProvider` as well as in `AppServiceProvider` to no avail

Comment: @AlexanderLomia - Be sure that you're handling this in `boot` method of the model, or you are doing this by loading model observers!